# WSO2 IS : Deployment using Helm

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Source : https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management/install/helm/get-started/

Based on source documentation, I could not find wso2/is-pattern1 chart in the helm repo. Can anyone guide?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the helm chart name that you have given. Try correcting it.

The correct command should be: (according to what you have given)

```
helm install wso2-5.11.0-4 wso2/is-pattern-1 --version 5.11.0-4
```